# Why does browserify load every module before calling require?

Tags: javascript, browserify

I have a code something like this:

**index.js**

```
var x, a = 1;

if (a)
   x = require("./a");
else
   x = require("./b");

module.exports = x();
```

**a.js**

```
console.log("a is loaded");
module.exports = function (){
    console.log("a is running")
};
```

**b.js**

```
console.log("b is loaded");
module.exports = function (){
    console.log("b is running")
};
```

By node I got

```
a is loaded
a is running
```

but by karma+browserify I got

```
a is loaded
b is loaded
a is running
```

in the console.

Is there a way to prevent b from loading by browserify?

Answer (score 1):

Please, someone correct me if I'm wrong, but the way browserify works is that it takes every JS file that you may need, and create a single JS with everything, so that it may be used in a browser; since it can't determine which of the sources you will need to use at compile time, it will need to load everything.

Maybe you could try using an alternate script loader, like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), for example.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It could easily put code b into a function which never runs, so the `console.log("b is loaded")` would never run. Apparently it does not do that, or does not do that properly.